# jsonrpc(jabsorb) is not sending data with POST request with IE=10 and IE=Edge document modes

Tags: internet-explorer, post, internet-explorer-11, json-rpc, ie11-developer-tools

I'm using [jabsorb](https://code.google.com/p/jabsorb/) in my application. I'm initializing the client using the following code:
`td.api = new JSONRpcClient(CB_ApiLoaded, "/td/json/baseApi");`

This code sends POST request to the URL mentioned and returns response in `CB_ApiLoaded` callback method. Here are the signatures of callback method:
`function CB_ApiLoaded(/*Array*/ result, /*Object*/ error) 
{
}`

I'm getting `error=null` and `result=JSON object` response in callback method on all browsers. But, on IE-11, I'm getting `error=JSON object` and `result=null` which is a problem. I've tried to reload the page after changing the Document Mode of IE to Edge, 10 & 9 and below are the details of requests sent in each Mode.

**Request Captured by IE-11 Developer Tools [Document Mode=Edge(Default) & 10]**

Request Headers:
[image: Request Headers]

Request Body:
[image: Request Body]

**Request Captured by IE-11 Developer Tools [Document Mode=9]**

Request Headers:
[image: Request Headers]

Request Body:
[image: Request Body]

So, as you can see that using Document Mode 11 & Edge, IE doesn't POST any data with request due to which server sends back error message mentioned below:
`{"error":{"code":590,"msg":"couldn't parse request arguments"}}`

Anyone who can help me with this that why IE is not sending data with POST request when using Edge & 10 document modes? Is this some issue with IE?

Thanks